# How to design the collapsed view of my custom ActivityDesigner

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

The built-in designers of activities like `Sequence` can be collapsed to a more compact view. In my custom [activity designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.componentmodel.design.activitydesigner.aspx), the collapse button is there (at right top) but apparently nothing happens if I click it. I want it to collapse to just showing the title bar (like the `Delay` activity). Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[There is a sample in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744850.aspx)

And [another one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489419.aspx).

Comment: can you point out the part that shows how to do the collapsed view?

Comment: Did you read and test the sample? It should be obvious, look at the names.